# Finite powerful set

Tags: real-analysis

A subset $S$ of positive real numbers is called *powerful* if for any two distinct elements $a,b$ of $S$, at least one of $a^b$ or $b^a$ is also an element of $S$.

a) Give an example of a four elements powerful set.

b) Prove that every finite powerful set has at most four elements.

**My fork so far**

а) An example of four numbers: $1$, $\frac12$, $\frac14$, $\frac1{16}$.
$$1^x=1, (\frac1{16})^{1/2}=\frac14, (\frac1{16})^{1/4}=\frac12, (\frac14)^{1/2}=\frac12$$